# Use Javascript to call function in models.py and update model field

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am developing an ecommerce website. I want my customers to view updated total_price field on the sidebar located alongside the order form. My model.py looks as follows:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    Customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    no_of_pages = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    def total_price(self):
        price_per_page = 20
        return no_of_pages * price_per_page
```

Now I have my views.py and forms.py. I have also rendered a html template to display the form and allow the user to place the order by indicating the number of pages. My views.py is as follows:

```
def OrderView(request):
    order_list = Order.objects.all()
    if request.POST:
        form = OrderingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'orderingsystem/ordercreate.html', {"form": OrderingForm})
```

My aim is to display a the total price on the side of the order page as soon as the customer selects number of pages without any HttpResponse because the form is not yet submitted at this stage.

For example:

If the Customer selects one page, the total price to be displayed = 1 * 20 = 20; if the customer selects 2 pages, the sidebar widget that displays total price updates automatically to 2 * 20 = 40, without any Http call. In other words, I want something like JavasScript to call `def total_price()` in my model `Order` without having to submit the form. Upon submission, it is then the form will be saved into my database. Anyone with an idea please?

Comment: You can make http call without forms

Comment: How do I do that?